# Calculating standard error of the mean for dose response assays when the data in the points is processed?

Tags: mean, error, dose-response

I am trying to report honest statistics about an experiment. I do not have a statistics background and am unsure how to approach this question.

My experiment measures a signal (S) minus background control (C) for each data point, this is the 'response'. The points are plotted against concentration, the 'dose'. I measure both the signal and the background control in indepedent experiments and I duplicate the experiment according to good scientific practice. In the field, this is called 'N=2'.

I assume then for some dose, I have:

S<sub>N=1</sub>, S<sub>N=2</sub>, C<sub>N=1</sub>, <sub>N=2</sub>

A point for a given dose is the average, like this:

((S<sub>N=1</sub>-C<sub>N=1</sub>)+(S<sub>N=2</sub>-C<sub>N=2</sub>))/2

From this average, I can get a standard deviation, and then I could say N=2 for the two measurements, and calculate the SEM for each data point.

But I don't know if this is correct? N is also written as samples sometimes, so that could be 4. Also I could instead average the two signals and the two controls seperately, and then subtract them to get the data points. Then I guess I would add the standard deviation for both S<sub>N</sub> and C<sub>N</sub> and divide by N=4? Other lab mates have brought up propagation of error and that also changes based on how I do the math, further confusing me.

I don't know which method is correct or how to rigorously figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "measure both the signal and the background control in indepedent experiments" - how independent are these measures exactly? Is it for example one person doing both a control and a signal-producing task, or is it one person doing the control and another the signal? (You have not elaboratd on what you're measuring or how so I cannot be more specific either)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.